# OWIN WebAPI 2 Bearer authentication custom identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

I want to allow two types of authentication on my site :
 * Forms authentication: The user login using his/her details in the form. The authentication should be made using cookies.
 * Bearer: When calling WebAPI's (for mobile), the authentication should be made **only** by using bearer tokens.

I've relayed on the SPA template and some questions in SO and did successful made it available.
The only problem I'm facing is the ClaimsIdentity: I wish to use custom identity class. However, I'm being able to do so only in forms authentication, not in bearer WebAPI requests.

My custom identity:

```
public class MyIdentity : ClaimsIdentity, IMyIdentity
{
    #region IMyIdentity

    private Account _account = null;

    public Account Account
    {
        get
        {
            if (_account == null)
            {
                if (this.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    Guid claimedAccountId = Guid.Parse(this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

                    var accountService = ServiceLocator.SharedInstance.GetInstance<IAccountService>();

                    _account = accountService.Where(
                        a => a.Id == claimedAccountId
                        ).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                _account = _account ?? Membership.Account.GuestAccount;
            }

            return _account;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In Global.asax, I've overridden the `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` method in order to set the custom identity, and it does working good - *but only in forms, not in WebAPI*.

In addition, I do set in WebApiConfig.cs

```
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

so it does make sense that MyIdentity being nulled and User.Identity resets back to ClaimsIdentity.

So to sum up my question - is there a way to define which Identity class will be used, so I can set MyIdentity instead of ClaimsIdentity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Web API, you could try hooking into the OWIN authentication pipeline, and implement your own Authentication Filter, and use it to change the current principal to your own:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
 {

        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                 if (context.Principal != null && context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                 {
                       CustomPrincipal myPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();

                       // Do work to setup custom principal

                       context.Principal = myPrincipal;
                 }

               return Task.FromResult(0);
 }
```

And register the filter:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthenticationFilter());
            ...
```